# Oracle collect function creating internal type and privileges to PUBLIC

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using `COLLECT` function in my query, and it is creating internal system generated type even though it is CAST to an already existing SQL type collection

Something like this:

```
cast(collect(opentrades_id)as t_dds_number)
```

Now it is creating an internally created type like `SYSTPZrEBTIYRDGYUI==`

Also, the user is giving executing rights to PUBLIC.

I want to understand why it is creating a system generated type and giving execute privileges to PUBLIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just the way it works.

In order to cast *TO* something, we have to be casting *FROM* something, so we silently create that to cater for the need

```
SQL> create table t as select rownum x
  2  from dual connect by level <= 10;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select type_name from user_types;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> select cast(collect(x) as sys.odcinumberlist) from t;

CAST(COLLECT(X)ASSYS.ODCINUMBERLIST)
----------------------------------------------------------------
ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> select type_name from user_types;

TYPE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------
ST000012SwVFQsQ4m5aVQ27Pg9mw=

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select text from user_source
  2  where name = 'ST000012SwVFQsQ4m5aVQ27Pg9mw=';

TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE         "ST000012SwVFQsQ4m5aVQ27Pg9mw=" AS TABLE OF NUMBER
```

Addenda - workaround to avoid type

```
SQL> select cast(multiset(select x from t) as sys.odcinumberlist) from dual;

CAST(MULTISET(SELECTXFROMT)ASSYS.ODCINUMBERLIST)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: So what can we do in order to avoid the system generated types created?

Comment: Also why execute privilege is being given to PUBLIC for that type?

Comment: @MorienMoses as Connor said, that's the way it works. If you want to avoid that, raise an enhancement request with Oracle Support to ask for the internal implementation of the `collect` function to be changed.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I understand it works that way but what is the reason behind giving execute privilege to PUBLIC. Are there any activities that needs to be performed that required execute privilege to PUBLIC. If yes I want to understand what it is.

Comment: @MorienMoses what would the alternative be? The database doesn't know who will be executing the query in the future. And why does it matter anyway?

Comment: I've made an addenda to workaround type creation if its really concerning you

Comment: The workaround will work when `collect` is meant to aggregate over all rows in its input rowset, but not in general. `collect` is an aggregate function (it works with `group by`); `multiset` is not.